# Django tests returning login redirect 302, even though user is logged in

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm extremely confused as to how to test pages that require a login.  I keep getting a 302 instead of a 200 in my response, and in inspecting the response in pdb I am definitely redirecting to a login page.  I am using login middleware instead of the decorator, if that's relevant.

```
class SimplePageLoadsTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('test_user')
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_user')

    def test_login(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.user.is_authenticated())

    def test_index(self):
        self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_user')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The `test_login` test passes.  I wasn't sure whether or not I needed to re-login the user per test (I think not, since I didn't need in `test_login`, but I've tried it both ways with the same result.  I threw a few print statements in my view, and they do not output, so I know I'm not hitting the view at all, like I suspected.

I can provide the view or middleware if they're relevant.

EDIT:  I disabled the middleware and replaced it with the @login_required decorator, and had the same problem.

EDIT AGAIN:  Just to check, I took out all login checks, and everything worked (as I expected).  So I'm nearly positive that the self.client just doesn't know I've logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are [creating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager) your user with a password.  Without providing a password it is considered a user that [cannot be logged in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password). Providing a password to `create_user` should fix it

```
self.client = Client()
self.user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', password='test_user')
self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test_user')
```

Comment: I'll try that, but then why is the test_login function working?

Comment: docs suggest is_authenticated always returns True, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Comment: You can also use `self.client.force_login(self.user)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login

Comment: this and `force_login` not working in Django 2.0.4 :(